# Subquery in Insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to use subquery in insert query but i'm getting error. How can i solve this?

```
insert into classes_has_students (id,student_id,class_id) 
values (
    (select id from students where first_name = 'Subhan'),
    (select id from classes where class_name = 'FSC')
)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: What error are you getting?  Your code should work.

Comment: ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 1: insert into classes_has_students (id,student_id,class_id)

Comment: Always quote any errors in full in your post. "i'm getting error" is not a problem description.

Comment: Thanks, next time i'll quote my error.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `id` in the columns list.  Presumably, it is assigned automatically so you can leave it out:

```
insert into classes_has_students (student_id, class_id) 
    values ( (select id from students where first_name = 'Subhan'),
             (select id from classes where class_name = 'FSC')
           )
```

Otherwise, you need to give it a value:

```
insert into classes_has_students (id, student_id, class_id) 
    values ( 42,
             (select id from students where first_name = 'Subhan'),
             (select id from classes where class_name = 'FSC')
           )
```